# How to track down the reason of temporary OpenSQL query slowdown?

Tags: sql, performance, abap, opensql, sap-basis

I have temporary performance problem in Z-transaction.

This transaction executes some SELECT query(few joins: AFKO, AUFK, AFPO, JEST, AFVV) and the performance is OK in general(~2 sec to get all results).
However from time to time this query runs 20x slower(35-40 sec). The amount of records returned by the query is almost the same in both cases.

The question is: How to track down the reason of such temporary query slowdown?

Comment: Google about ST12 and ST05 (SQL trace)

Comment: Depending on the exact SELECT and conditions, the database may choose different strategies to access the data (different index, change the sequence of table accesses in joins), and some data may be already buffered or not. You have to compare the execution plans, statistics (buffer reads). PS: the fact that the queries returned the same number of records doesn't mean that the queries have read the same amount of data, i.e. one may have read the whole table, and the other may have read only 1% of the table !